# Simple webpage cannot load some image from MySQL database, some works well

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a simple webpage and a database to upload and show image on webpage.However, some image cannot be downloaded and shown correctly on webpage, some images show well. I have checked my database, each image can be inserted into database correctly.

My PHP code is below:

```
<?php
    ini_set('mysql.connect_timeout',10);
    ini_set('default_socket_timeout',5);

    include_once 'dbconnect.php';


?>



    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['btn_Upload_Image']))
    {   
        if(getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) == FALSE)
        {
            // echo "Please select an image.";
            ?>
                    <script>alert('Please select an image.');</script>
            <?php
        }
        else
        {
            $image= addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
            $Name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
            $image= file_get_contents($image);
            $image= base64_encode($image);
            saveimage($Name,$image);
         }

    }
    //displayimage();



    function saveimage($Name,$Image)
            {

                $qry="Insert into Clothing (Picture_Name,Picture_Storage) values ( '$Name','$Image')";

                // echo "$qry" ."</br>";
                $result=mysql_query($qry);
                if($result)
                {   
                    ?>
                    <script>alert('Image uploaded.');</script>
                    <?php
                }
                else
                {   
                    ?>
                    <script>alert('Image not uploaded.');</script>
                    <?php
                }
            }



    function displayimage()
            {   
                $qry = "Select * from Clothing";

                $result=mysql_query($qry);

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    echo '<img height="200" width="200" src="data:image;base64,'.$row[Picture_Storage].' "> ';
                }
            }


?>



<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Hello PeekABuy</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>


    <body>

    <div id="header">
        <div id="left">
        <label>Cropped Images </label>
        </div>
    </div>


<div id="body">
    <div id="Hotel-InfoForm">
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <center>
            <table align="center" width="40%" border="0">


            <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="file" name="image" />
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" name="btn_Upload_Image" value="Upload" />

            </td>   
            </tr>
            <center>
            </table>


            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>


        </form> 

            <?php
                displayimage();
            ?>

        <br> 
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>


        <hr>


    </div>
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

[1:How webpage looks like; 2: Datatype of my database; 3: Inserting status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muCmp.png)

> Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). `addslashes()` is NOT a defense and is utterly USELESS for this.

Comment: Do you mean I need to delete addslashes()? I have deleted it and check the result, it is still the same, some can be shown, some cannot. And I am confusing about the link you shared with me. Thank you  though.

Comment: Please don't use mysql_* functions - especially if you are learning. No-one needs you to write new database code with 10 year old database code that is prone to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Sorry. I can't quite understand you. Yes, I am still learning, I just try to find a way fix my problem, but I don't write new database code.

Comment: use PHP Data Objects (PDO) for your queries.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: I will check them, thanks all!

Comment: Just curious. Why do you do this? `$image = file_get_contents($image);` What happens if you comment it out? and run the code without it?

Comment: @Ryan Vincent, that is a line of source code I learned online about how to upload an images to database.

Comment: Finally, I set my database Picture_Storage's datatype from BLOB to LongBLOB, then I can upload all of my pictures. I fixed it. Thank you all, appreciate your suggestions.